# Ansible inventory from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, ansible, inventory

I have a query on Ansible inventory. Is it possible to load the inventory from a MySQL db than from a file? I am looking for specifying the host machine ssh keys stored in a My SQL DB while invoking a playbook. The reason for this approach is that as per my understanding, in order to provision a host machine through ansible the ssh key should be added to the known hosts file to avoid the password prompt and enable key based login. In a fully automated environment I want to avoid the password entry and storing password in a file has obvious security issues.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use Ansible's [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) to load inventory data from anywhere. Take a look at the AWS inventory script for an example of calling an API for a list of instances.

> The reason for this approach is that as per my understanding, in order to provision a host machine through ansible the ssh key should be added to the known hosts file to avoid the password prompt and enable key based login.

Not necessarily. If you're on something like AWS where instances come and go frequently, you can turn off host key checking in your Ansible config with [`host_key_checking=False`](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#host-key-checking). This has security implications you should be aware of, but is pretty common when working with short-lived instances like those you'd see on AWS.

> In a fully automated environment I want to avoid the password entry and storing password in a file has obvious security issues.

It should be noted that Ansible has an [encrypted vault](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html) you can use for passwords. Key-based authentication is generally the way to go, though.

Comment: Your host_key_checking and dynamic inventory links are 404ing
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html#managing-host-key-checking
and
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html
look to work as replacements